# Reading a remote file with java on linux

Tags: java, linux, apache, file

I need to read a remote file using a java app, but the file is in apache server on linux.
I tried with "\\" but doesn't work like windows.
How can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a remote file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316360/reading-a-remote-file-using-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the URL class:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

This is the standard way of reading files from a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing your file via web browser using url formatted like:

```
http://server-name-or-ip/path/filename
```

When you see your file in browser, use that url from your Java app, too.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a number of things. But we don't really know what question you're asking. Are you asking how to retrieve a document over HTTP? How to do a file copy from Linux? Network shares?

If the file is served by the webserver (in the docroot), the easiest way is probably to request it over HTTP using the `URL` class as stated above.

If the file is NOT under the webroot (i.e. can't be specified as `http://webserver.name/some/path/to/file`) then you'll need to use some other method. I'm assuming this is what you meant - you mention `\\`, the Windows file-sharing (SMB) protocol prefix. The easiest way is to use SSH and `scp`/`sftp`, which is probably already installed on the Linux machine - you may need to enable it, and you'll need a login. Then it's as simple as `scp user@host:/remote/file/path local/path`. You can set up SSH keys to avoid a password.