# Reading a property file from a remote location using getResourceAsStream() method

Tags: java, properties

Can I use the below code to read a propery file from a remote location in internet?

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/filename.properties");
Properties pro = new Properties();
pro.load(is);
// ...
```

Can I replace the `/filename.properties` in to a remote path like `192.168.173.238/D:/war/filename.properties`? If yes, how should I specify the path? This code is running in Apache Tomcat.

Comment: I don't understand the question... It is just a question of obtaining an `InputStream` from the remote source (which you do not even say what it is!!) and using `new Properties().load()`...

Comment: Why would you want to use `Class.getResourceAsStream`? If you're fetching it from the internet, surely you want some stream from a URL connection or something similar...

Comment: By the way, beware of this very annoying trap: the `.load()` method reads in ISO-8859-1. If you want read using another charset, use the .load()` method having a `Reader` as an argument (for instance, `new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a remote file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316360/reading-a-remote-file-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

If it's available by an URL (like as you would enter in your webbrowser's address bar), use `URL#openStream()` or `URLConnection#getInputStream()`.

```
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
```

If it's available by a local disk file system path (like as you would enter in your disk explorer's address bar), use `FileInputStream`.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Simple as that.

Your next question shall probably be, *"What's the right URL or disk file system path?"*. This can't be answered based on the information provided so far.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi Can I use the below code to read a propery file from a remote location in internet.

Probably not. You can only use it to read a property file that is available on the CLASSPATH. Unless you are using something like the RMI codebase feature, or URLClassLoaders, your CLASSPATH does not include network locations.

You don't seem to understand what `getResourceAsStream()` is actually for.