# Reading file from PATH of URI

Tags: java, io, java-io

I have to read a file which can be local or in remote.
The file path or `URI` will come form user input.
Currently I am reading only local file,this way

```
public String readFile(String fileName)
{

    File file=new File(fileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ( (line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null ) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File : \""+file.getAbsolutePath()+"\" Not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The parameter `String fileName` is the user input which can be a path to local file or a `URI`
How can i modify this method to work with both `Local path` and `URI` ?

Comment: You may have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316360/reading-a-remote-file-using-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suposing you have the [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) in `String fileName` you can read url easily with:

```
URI uri = new URI(filename);
File f = new File(uri);
```

Check [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html) for further info

Comment: pardon me if i am mistaken,But i don't see any `toURI()` method in `String` class

Comment: sorry, i forgot string to uri conversion xDDDD

Comment: thanks. I found a good hint from your answer but to the exact one. please edit you answer, i think there are still some thing to make it clear, like `url.toURI()` on a `URI` object (i guess a typo)  and i don't need to consider `URL`

Answer (score 0):

File class has also a constructor based on the URI so it easy to say new File(uri).. and everything stays the same.
However, the URI is system-dependent, as specification says "An absolute, hierarchical URI with a scheme equal to "file", a non-empty path component, and undefined authority, query, and fragment components".

I think that if you need to read something remote, the best way to do it is by using Sockets.