# How to fetch remote file using Client Interface in java

Tags: java, string, httpclient, inputstream

I have a file located remotely at url : `www.something.com/abc.txt`.

I want to fetch this remote file`(abc.txt)` and store it in `InputStream` or `String` object using 'Client' Interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a remote file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316360/reading-a-remote-file-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
String url = "http://www.example.com/README.txt";
// Create a method instance.
GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
// Provide custom retry handler is necessary
method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));
byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
String fileContents = new String(responseBody);
```

[Here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) is also a nice tutorial that can help you out

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HttpClientUtil {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

        try {

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://txt2html.sourceforge.net/sample.txt");
            httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            String strValue = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println(strValue);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(response);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(httpClient);
        }

    }
}
```

Here are the dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```