# Java Spring pipe remote file into multipart upload

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I have an image at location X. I want to copy it to location Y which accepts form data. I dont want to download the file to a temp file on my server but instead pipe it.
My current setup uses a temp file.

```
  public Asset pipeToY(File tempFileFromX) {
    Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(tempFileFromX.getPath());
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("file", resource);
    // map.add("otherInfos");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + myTokenForY);
    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(
        map, headers);

    try {
      ResponseEntity<Object> result = restTemplate.exchange(locationY, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
          Object.class);
      HashMap<String, String> resultMap = (HashMap<String, String>) result.getBody();
      return convert(resultMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // ...
    }
  }
```

How can I replace that part with a piped stream?

```
public Asset pipeToY(String urlX) {
    Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(???)
}
```

Comment: Instead of downloading pipe it directly to the other one. You have an inputstream and copy directly to the other one.

Comment: Can you do something like what described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316360/reading-a-remote-file-using-java. Read a remote resource to a stream and pipe the stream to an output stream?